# HashMap creating duplicate keys?

Tags: java, hashmap, directed-graph

I have a class `Vertex` defined as:

```
class Vertex {
    private String s;

    public Vertex(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setName(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public boolean equals(Vertex o) {
        return s.equals(o.getName());
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }
}
```

and a class `DirectedGraph` with the following methods:

```
private HashMap<Vertex, HashSet<Vertex>> adjacencyMap = new HashMap<>();

public boolean addVertex(Vertex v) {
    if (!this.adjacencyMap.containsKey(v)) {
        this.adjacencyMap.put(v, new HashSet<>());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean addEdge(Vertex x, Vertex y) {
    if (adjacencyMap.containsKey(x) && adjacencyMap.containsKey(y)) {
        if (!adjacencyMap.get(x).contains(y)) {
            adjacencyMap.get(x).add(y);
            edgeCount++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public DirectedGraph(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String l = s.nextLine();
        int i = 0;
        Vertex parent = null;
        for (String t : l.split(" ")) {
            if (i == 0) {
                parent = new Vertex(t);
                if (root == null) {
                    root = parent;
                }
                addVertex(parent);
            } else {
                Vertex v = new Vertex(t);
                addVertex(v);
                if (addEdge(parent, v) != true) System.out.println(parent + ", " + v + "failed");
                // System.out.println("adding edge: " + parent + ", " + v);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    s.close();
    for (Vertex v : adjacencyMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(v + ": \n    " + adjacencyMap.get(v));
    }
}
```

as you can see, it takes a file and scans it line by line, assuming the first node is a "parent" node and the following depend on it. If I use the following input text file:

```
B D G
C A
E B F H
J B
I C
```

My issue is that my output is:

```
A: 
    []
J: 
    []
F: 
    []
C: 
    []
J: 
    [B]
B: 
    []
C: 
    []
G: 
    []
E: 
    [F, B, H]
B: 
    []
H: 
    []
A: 
    [J, C, E]
I: 
    [C]
B: 
    [G, D]
D: 
    []
E: 
    []
C: 
    [A]
```

As you can see, my `HashMap` has multiple duplicate keys because I must not understand how `containsKey` works. I have two ideas to resolve my issue:
 firstly, and more cave-manish, is to simply iterate over the `keySet()`, manually compare the Vertex's names, and combine the `.get()`s, or
update addVertex or addEdge, whichever is the primary offender, to recognize duplicate keys.
 I'm not sure how to do either, so a shove in the right direction would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap` uses hashing function to calculate indices for objects used as `key`. For this functionality to work properly you need to provide both `equals()` AND `hashCode()` functions for class that instances of you plan to use as keys in your hash map.
That means you need to override `public int hashCode()` method that's now inherited straight from `Object` superclass, and put there some calculations that will return the same integer for objects that are considered 'equal'. Fortunately you compare `String`s as this criteria so you can use `String` method `hashCode` resulting with:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return s.hashCode();
}
```

Second problem that I previously missed is your implementation of `equals()` is wrong. You should `override` `Object`'s `equals()` which has a signature `public boolean equals( Object o )` and you implemented it with `Vertex` as an argument, which caused that while adding to hashmap `Object`'s `equals was used, as you didn't override by overload` equals`. That's one of the reasons that annotation` @Override`should be used, compiler would tell you that you don't override anything and you would know that you're doing something wrong. Now, going back to how to implement`equals` properly....

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if( o instanceof Vertex ) {
        return s.equals((( Vertex)o).getName());
    } else { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now instances of `Vertex` will behave properly when used as key in hash map.

As a side note, putting all the logic, including opening, parsing file in constructor is a little too much to my taste, consider splitting it into some methods instead.

Comment: output is alphabetical now, but the duplicate keys are still there.

Comment: @ganondork see updated answer, next time provide code sample that compiles, that will make it easier to run your code and both test your problem and possible solution.

Comment: It compiles in Eclipse just fine. The compiler was the one who told me to either remove override or revert it back to the original signature, I just picked one of the options without realizing this would be a consequence. Thank you for making it clear to me!